# Move just 2 matchsticks to make three equally sized triangles

Tags: mathematics, geometry, matches

There are 9 equally sized matchsticks, move 2 to make 3 equal triangles
[image: The puzzle]

Comment: is 3 equal a condition?

Comment: Does equal mean congruent, or just similar?

Comment: Hm.. What's the trick here? 3D? Negative space?

Comment: What would be the answer??

Answer (score 6):

If moving means applying force, we can bend the rule without breaking it.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

> Take one match and lay it horizontally across the top two (red in picture below)
>  Take another match, break it into thirds, and lay two of the pieces down (two greens)

Picture (may not be to scale):

> [image: 1]

Comment: It's not "2 moves".

Comment: @mimic The question said "move 2" which I interpret as "move 2 matchsticks" not "make 2 moves".

Comment: Well, okay, but "move" usually doesn't mean "break".

Comment: @mimic Given the fact that no one has solved this puzzle in 6+ months, I think lateral thinking is required.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite sure what the trick is, but I can at least get four triangles with three moves:

> [image]
>  Six in four, of course, trivially follows.

Answer (score 3):

This is the only kind of arrangement I can think of:

> [image]
>
>  It creates the ***vertices*** of three small isosceles triangles at A, B and C.
>
>  There are similar arrangements possible – the two matches can be moved up or down to make other shapes of congruent triangle.

Comment: It seems like you could get four triangles with this logic.

Comment: @Weather Vane, apologies, but I still do not see the triangles?

Comment: @SagarChand after several hours no one had solved the puzzle so I posted this, and now even after a day there is no other solution that moves only two matches. Keep looking!

Comment: @WeatherVane I suspect there is no correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Could not do it by moving 2 matchsticks but by moving 3 or 4 matchsticks gives me some lucrative results.

This is by 3 moves

> [image: 3Moves]

These are by 4 moves

> [image: 4MoveA] [image: 4MoveB]